# Ports not accessable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I installed docker and issues a 'docker swarm init' command.

I'm trying to launch a stack using the following command: docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml mystack

The docker-compose file can be found [here](https://github.com/tonsV2/ip2flag/blob/master/docker-compose.yml), the first docker file [here](https://github.com/tonsV2/ip2flag/blob/master/Dockerfile) and the second [here](https://github.com/tonsV2/ip2country/blob/master/Dockerfile)

The output of 'docker ps' is:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
f582b3e8d33e        tons/ip2country:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'java -D…"   8 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        8080/tcp                 ip2flag_country-service.1.t5rvuqaw8tj7v20u0xo0dgy6x
bbf2c8304f1a        tons/ip2flag:latest      "/bin/sh -c 'java -D…"   10 seconds ago      Up 8 seconds        8080/tcp                 ip2flag_app.1.z00gz8adj2yshpgimaw2o55d3
cbc7eaace4bf        portainer/portainer      "/portainer"             39 minutes ago      Up 39 minutes       0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp   portainer
```

The output of 'docker service ls' is:

```
ID                  NAME                      MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                    PORTS
ex51pyh1oyyo        ip2flag_app               replicated          1/1                 tons/ip2flag:latest      *:8080->8080/tcp
yhbt97lmjqan        ip2flag_country-service   replicated          1/1                 tons/ip2country:latest
```

Since I'm running this on localhost I'd expect http://localhost:8080/ to return some sort of data. But it just times out. If I attach to the container and execute something like wget localhost:8080/some/path it works as expected. So the service is running and within the container listening to port 8080. However the port isn't exposed outside of dockers net. Further more I can add that launching with 'docker-compose up' works just fine too. But not with 'docker stack deploy'. Any clue about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: run docker inspect ex51pyh1oyyo and find container ip you can access wtih that ip with out mention port rather then 80

Comment: @Adiii Inspect lists two virtual ip's... Neither are accessable. Here is the complete output: https://nopaste.xyz/?01dbeb6c605f27e3#4uZLtJ1umCWvQJ3bET4bWHqeNnQMTWnxI3jdL0VfUAI=

Comment: you are running docker on vm?

Comment: No, no docker machine or anything a like here

Comment: Btw why you using docker swarm

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/swarm/swarm_at_scale/deploy-app/

Comment: That links seems deprecated. I'm using docker swarm because I'm testing if it's something we want to use in production

Comment: okay good firest i will recomend to run with out docker swarm so you will come to know the actual problem with container or with docker swarms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168206/discussion-between-adiii-and-user672009).

Comment: I guess the java daemon is listen on localhost only? `CMD java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar *.jar` That would explain why you can request it inside the container, but it ignores requests from outside the docker container.